# ARR route to servers

Tags: iis, arr

I'm trying to get ARR running in a test environment. I have 3 servers and setup a web farm. From there I enabled load balancing on each node except the primary.

What it seems like its doing is the requests are getting handled by the primary server (even though it's not enabled for load balance). If I stop the site on the primary server, my requests no longer work. If I enable, then requests work again.

Is there another step that I'm missing to get this working?

Comment: I may be closer on a path. My ARR server was also a node in my WebFarm. The bindings on a website take higher priority than the URLRewrite's, so my Site was answering before URL_Rewrite could pass to ARR.

Comment: My last comment was the problem. I had the website bindings accepting the request. URLRewrite needs to apply a rule to route to the WebFarm and it wasn't getting the chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bindings on a website take higher priority than the URLRewrite's, so my Site was answering before URL_Rewrite could pass to ARR